# Update Gridview to existing sql table in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, gridview

I am exporting data from excel and show it in gridview and when I click submit, it needs to be updated in existing table.

Below is my excel data

S.No.   RequestID   Subdivision No  Parcel No   CUID    Status  Remarks
1        5           42             55            55    Open    Pending

I have successfully exported and show it in Gridview. Now I want to update the same in the existing table(Tablename:ParcelInf).

Below is my table detail

```
Table ParcelInf(
[RequestID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
FormattedRequestID AS ('CUID' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(RequestID AS VARCHAR(10)),10)),
[SubdivisionNo] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[ParcelNo] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[Region] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[City] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[Zone] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[CoordinateSystem] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[CUID] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[Status] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[Remarks] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[UpdateDate] [date] NULL,
[RequestedBy] [nvarchar] (20) NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (RequestID) REFERENCES RequestInf (RequestID)
```

Below is my code

```
private void BindGrid()
    {
        string Constr = null;
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        string UpdateQuery = null;
        Constr = "Data Source=WIN-A876U316VGA;integrated security=true;Initial Catalog=CUIDinfo";
        con = new SqlConnection(Constr);

        DataTable dtProducts = new DataTable("ParcelInf");

        dtProducts.Columns.Add("Status");
        dtProducts.Columns.Add("Remarks");
        foreach (DataRow DR in dtProducts.Rows)
        {
            con.Open();

            UpdateQuery = "Update ParcelInf Set Status='" + DR["Status"] + "',Remarks='" + DR["Remarks"] + "' where RequestID=" + DR["RequestID"] ;
            cmd = new SqlCommand(UpdateQuery, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }

    }


}
```

Its not throwing any error but it is not updating the data into SQL

Comment: Have you stepped through the code?

Comment: Is this winform or web?

Comment: The datatable dtproducts will not have any data then how will t update

Answer (score 0):

Check the page lifecycle, i guess you are not calling BindGrid() on page_load even on PostBack so for sure dtProducts.Rows.Count will be zero.

So add this code to Page_Load event:

```
if (!IsPostBack) BindGrid();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your datatable 'dtProducts' is empty each time as you are creating a new object.
2. See you code

   ```
   DataTable dtProducts = new DataTable("ParcelInf");
   dtProducts.Columns.Add("Status");
   dtProducts.Columns.Add("Remarks");
   foreach (DataRow DR in dtProducts.Rows)
   {
       con.Open();

       UpdateQuery = "Update ParcelInf Set Status='" + DR["Status"] + "',Remarks='" + DR["Remarks"] + "' where RequestID=" + DR["RequestID"] ;
       cmd = new SqlCommand(UpdateQuery, con);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       cmd.Dispose();
       con.Close();
   }
   ```

   You are not fetching any value from your grid in your table object. so the loop count is 0 always.

   - Debug the code once and check row count.
   - Retry filling the values, it would work.